# Не переведён текст в пункте по участию в opt на странице настроек

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/10891

Предложил:

> Принять участие в тестировании (подробнее)

Comment: Кто-то утвердил.